# Error writing to database

Tags: moodle

I'm using Moodle 3.2.
Created website in XAMPP server with database type is mariaDB.
Trying to move website in to WAMP server.
Created database in phpmyadmin and imported database.
Placed website folder in WAMP/www/site_folder.
changed configuration in config.php file.

While running the site, getting the following error.

**Error writing to database**

Answer (score 0):

Try to run a plain moodle install before, to see if your DB configuration is working fine.
I think for MariaDB you need to set some (not standard) settings for moodle 3.2

Answer (score 0):

You seems to have switched from mysql to mariaDB, Please make sure that you have set the dbtype driver right in config.php file.

`$CFG->dbtype = 'mariadb';`

See for reference https://docs.moodle.org/32/en/MariaDB